# Variable scope in child template view in ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm trying to declare defaults in my layout that can be overridden in the view.

This is my layout:

```
<%# Variables defaults -%>
<%
    @cssFiles = []
    @jsFiles = []
-%>
<%# Variables overrides -%>
<%= yield :layoutVariables -%>
```

And my view:

```
<% content_for :layoutVariables do -%>
    <%
        @cssFiles.push 'bootstrap'
        @jsFiles.push 'bootstrap'
    -%>
<% end -%>
```

I know this can be done by declaring the variables in the controller but I'd like to know whether the scope can extend from layout->view.

Comment: @Mori I wouldn't have posted this question if I hadn't tried it already :)  Unfortunately it throws an error due to lack of scope

Comment: And did you put that error into the question so we know what it says? Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are trying to collect some assets files inside the view. It is not very good option. 
I recommend to make new module

> config/initializers/frontend.rb:

```
Module Frontend
    @@fe = Array.new()

def self.getfe
   @@fe
end

def self.add_css(css)
            @@fe << css
        end
    end
```

And now you can simply add your css file anywhere to this array just simply call:

```
Frontend::add_css "yourfile"
```

And get your array back simply call

```
Frontend::getfe
```

This mechanism with class methods works in views also
Good luck!